# create array during for loop

Tags: php, arrays, iframe, if-statement

I have an array from POST ($coursevalues).  I need to say if the value is not numeric then add the value to the database.

Howvwer, as the page is in an iframe it is being sent data repeatedly and so if it has been added I want it not to do this.  Within the if true statement I added an array $newcourses which should contain the value.  Then I have added to the if statement, if not in the array $newcourses then add to database.

However, it still try to add to the database resulting in a MYSQL error - no duplicates are allowed in the table.

```
$y = 0;

foreach ($coursevalues as $key => $val) {
    // Try to prevent duplicate entry on refresh as value on other form stays
    // same - doesn't update to the ID. add or is a variable I made earlier.
    if (is_numeric($val) == false && !in_array($val, $newcourses)) {
        $newcourses[$y++] = $val;

        $tbl = 'tblCourses';
        $fieldcourse = 'CourseName';

        // This line creates a query that asks the server to create a table,
        // with the name and fields described above
        $insertQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl ($fieldcourse) VALUES ('$val')")
            or die ('Could not insert new course into tblCourses: ' . mysql_error());

        $coursevalues[$val] = mysql_insert_id();
    }
}
```

Can you check the statement to see if it works?  It's in PHP.

Comment: Are you clearing out the DB table each time you retry this code?

Comment: `However, it still try to add to the database resulting in a MYSQL error` -- what's the error?

Comment: `$coursevalues[$val] = mysql_insert_id();` - You shouldn't modify the array during iteration.

Comment: The error is Could not insert new course into tblCourses: Duplicate entry 'helllo' for key 'CourseName'

Comment: The value of `$newcourses` doesn't persist after the script is done btw, so this is a bad protection against duplicates. If it's okay to ignore those duplicates, do what Jim suggested and use `INSERT IGNORE`; alternatively, use `REPLACE INTO` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: I just need it to say if the value is in the array, do not try to add this value to the database again. The page is loaded regularly and so is now attempting to add an item in a listbox on the previous page, which has already been added - The if statement or coursevalues array isn't working.

At the moment It should say if not in the array then add it to the array and add it to the database.  Thus, if the same value comes to the if again, it will not add to the DB as it is in the array.

Comment: The problem is in the following sentence `the page is in an iframe`

Answer (score 1):

Use an `INSERT IGNORE` and mysql will ignore duplicate errors and insert the rest which aren't  duplicates.

I'd also re-build your code a little bit, because as it is you're running an insert query for every iteration of the loop. Instead, I'd do something more like

```
<?php
$new_courses = array();
foreach ($coursevalues as $val)
{
    if (!is_numeric($val) && !in_array($val, $new_courses)) {
        $new_courses []= $val;
    }
}

?>
```

Then I'd programatically build an insert query to insert this data into mysql like so:

```
<?php
$table = "tblCourses";
$field_course = "CourseName";
//the base insert query (with added ignore 
//to ignore courses that already have been inserted)
$insert_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO {$table} ({$field_course}) VALUES ";

$insert_parts = array();
//build the correct insert syntax and escape the value of the course name
foreach ($new_courses as $course) { 
    $insert_parts []= "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($course) . "')";
}

if (count($insert_parts) > 0) //make sure we are inserting at least 1 course
{
    //use implode to build a proper mysql multi-insert query which will
    //return a string similar to ('coursename'), ('coursename2'), ('coursename3')
    //and concatenate that to the $insert_query, and run it to mysql_query

    mysql_query($insert_query . implode(",", $insert_parts));
}
```

#### edit (regarding retaining your inserted id for cousrses)

To retain your inserted IDs for courses, I'd keep the above code and run a 2nd query at the end of everything to get all the ids for the courses that you tried to insert.

like so:

```
<?php
$course_id_map = array();
$course_ids = array();
$where_parts = array();

foreach ($new_courses as $course_name)
{
    $where_parts []= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($course_name) . "'";
}

$query = "SELECT id, {$field_course} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field_course} IN ("
       . implode(",", $where_parts) . ")";

$results = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    //creates a name=>id map of the courses posted
    $course_id_map[ $row[$field_course] ] = $row['id'];

    //creates a posted_id=>mysql_id map of the courses posted
    $course_ids[ array_search($row[$field_course], $coursevalues) ] = $row['id'];
}
```

The result of this code will get you an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    ["course2001"] => "201848",
    ["course2002"] => "201849",
    ["course2003"] => "201850",
    ["course2004"] => "201851",
    ["course2005"] => "201852"
)
```

#### end edit

Some other notes regarding your question:

1. At the bottom of your if statement, you're modifying your `$coursevalues` variable, I'm not really sure why. If you  need the inserted ID of each course later in your code, this example may not work for you.
2. (continued) Modifying that `$coursevalues` array at the bottom of your if statement creates a hard-to-read scenario for the future. At first glance it looks like you create an infinite loop for yourself. However, upon further inspection, you'll remember that the if statement excludes non-numeric values, so your loop will eventually terminate. This is a readability/code style problem that will bite you (or the maintainer) in the future. You should really refrain from doing stuff like that. Create another variable for tracking insert IDs if you need to, don't use the one you're sourcing your insert values from.
3. You should not be using the old (deprecated) `mysql` php extension, you should be using something newer, at least [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli), but preferably [`pdo`](http://php.net/pdo).
4. (more an efficiency in my answer) You could create the insert parts of the array instead of assigning them to the `$new_courses` variable and then looping again (read as: you could do what i showed above in 1 loop instead of 2). I just used 2 to make it more clear.

Comment: OK Thanks for that I have used your code.  I need the course value to become the last added ID.  Here is an example array:

`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => chem2001 )`

The value I added was chem2001, I need it to change chem2001 to it's ID.  The code later on needs this.  For example: 1 and 3 are Course ID's and are showing below, but obviously chem2001 is not as it is not in the CourseID column.

Comment: @user2561158 I edited my answer so you can retain your IDs of your inserted courses.

Comment: The displayed array still says `Array ( [0] => 66 [1] => HEYHEY [2] => werer )`

Comment: Here is the code I'm using `$course_ids = array(); $where_parts = array(); foreach ($new_courses as $course_name) { $where_parts []= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($course_name) . "'"; } $query = "SELECT CourseID, {$field_course} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field_course} IN (" . implode(",", $where_parts) . ")"; $results = mysql_query($query); while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { $course_ids[ $row[$field_course] ] = $row['CourseID']; }`

Comment: `$course_ids` has a map of all the `_POST`ed courses to their ID in the database. You can modify the code I wrote to either build the exact array structure you need, or modify your `$coursevalues` array to be more like what you expect/want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still unable to get the $coursevalues array to update but I think I'm close.

Thanks again :)

Comment: The code I wrote doesn't update `$coursevalues`, it creates a new array `$course_ids` which contains a `name`=>`id` map of your courses. Instead of doing that, for each result row you could loop through your  `$coursevalues` to see if the value is equal to the `$row['CourseName']` value, and if they are, change the `$coursevalues` value from the course name to the `$row['id']` value. That seems really convoluted, when what you really care about is probably the name and id together.

Comment: OK, Is it possible for `$course_ids` to be `id=>id` as that is what `$coursevalues` is.  Then instead of using `$coursevalues` in the next code I will simply use the new `$course_ids`

Comment: yeah, edited. I used [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) to locate the value of your course name in the `$coursevalues` array, and assigned the corresponding key to the value of the id in the database, which results in an array of the format `posted_id`=>`mysql_id`.